# How to delete Call code from a phone number in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I'm using [react-native-phone-number-input](https://github.com/garganurag893/react-native-phone-number-input) and i want to delete the call code from the number if the user types it.
my solution is :

```
    class PhoneUserInput extends PureComponent {
        ...
            <PhoneInput
                  ref={this.myRef}
                  onChangeFormattedText={(value) => {
                    if (value.substr(`+${this.myRef.current?.getCallingCode()}`.length)
.startsWith(`+${this.myRef.current?.getCallingCode()}`)) {
                      value = value.substr(`+${this.myRef.current?.getCallingCode()}`.length)
.replace(`+${this.myRef.current?.getCallingCode()}`, ''));
}
                      onChangeFormattedText(value);
                      console.log('formated value'+value);
                    }
                  }}
             />
    }
```

I tried to the same thing on `onChangeText` props but it's doesn't give the effect instantly on the component.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to do your work with

- onChangeText={ (_text)=>{ //Your code} }

AND add :

- value={value}

Here is a working example :

```
<PhoneInput
   ref={phoneInput}
   defaultValue={value}
   value={value}
   defaultCode="FR"
   layout="first"
   placeholder={label}
   containerStyle={styles.phoneContainer}
   onChangeText={(text) => {
                  setValue(text)
              }}
   onChangeFormattedText={(text) => {
                  setFormattedValue(text)
              }}
   withDarkTheme
   withShadow
 />
```